# Materialize TextArea not dynamically changing?

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Working with a TextArea, class="materialize-textarea". 
On the documentation at https://materializecss.com/forms.html there should be no javaScript or jQuery needed for the TextArea to expand downwards and move the page's content along with it.

When I enter text inside the TextArea I cannot hit enter to move down. I can only write along the line to infinity. Which is not what I want, obviously, what I want is for the TextArea to resize as the text reaches end of the row, but it doesn't. Anyone encountered this issue before?

```
HTML: 
<div class="container" id="applyDiv">
    <h4 class="header center green-text">APPLY FOR MEMBERSHIP</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
            <div class="row">


                <p class="light">
                    By submitting your company details you can get access to StoryTourist and create your own 
                    customized stories for your audience to enjoy around the world!
                </p>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix green-text">business</i>
                    <input placeholder="Company Name" type="text" class="validate">
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix green-text">mail outline</i>
                    <input placeholder="Company e-mail" type="text" class="validate">
                </div> 
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix green-text">phone</i>
                    <input placeholder="Company phone-number" type="text" class="validate">
                </div> 
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix green-text">mode_edit</i>
                    <input placeholder="Message us..." textarea id="textArea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                </div>


            </div>
        </form>
    </div>        
    <div class="row center padding-bottom-1">
        <a class="btn-small green" id="sendButton">Submit details</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Changed:

```
<input placeholder="Message us..." textarea id="textArea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
```

To:

```
<textarea placeholder="Message us..." textarea id="textArea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
```

Now faced with issue that page doesn't dynamically change with TextArea, there are no fixed heights in my CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this

```
<input placeholder="Message us..." textarea id="textArea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
```

To this

```
<textarea placeholder="Message us..." id="textArea1" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
```

That should fix your issue. You opened with an `<input>` tag but closed with a `</textarea>` tag.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the page doesn't dynamically change with the textarea, can you make a codepen?

Comment: What I mean is, that the TextArea should resize so you see all the text in the TextArea. Now it disappears as it moves upward as I press enter. 
The submit-button and footer should follow along, making the page-height larger as the text is expanding. Don't think I can give a more straight answer than that :)

Comment: I'd need to be at home to replicate the issue, if someone doesn't pick this up for you I'll have a look when I'm home from work, as unfortunately I still don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really late, but when you download the Materialize folder - if you want it to auto resize, materialize uses javascript, so you must include the javascript file as well as the css file

Comment: That helped. Thank you :)